# How to change order of reasonable defaults suggested by IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ 12.1 Ultimate, when i type `pub`, i would like for "public" to be first reasonable default instead of

[image]

How can i change order of suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA keeps track of the suggestions you choose the most often and prioritizes them automatically. There is no UI or settings for reordering the completion variants manually.